# MYSQL & PHP Search Query

Tags: php, mysql, search, mysqli

So I'm building a little Search Engine to work with a database I've created and I want this search engine to return multiple results when you search. For example if you put in Jo it would return both John and Joe. This is what I've built so far:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%" . $searchquery . "%' ");
  $results = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
  return $results;
```

The problem I'm having is I only get one result, Joe because of alphabetical order, but I want it to return both Joe John and whatever other results. I know I'm missing something or doing something wrong and I would appreciate any guidance! Cheers!

Comment: Probably because you're fetching only one(first) row from the result set and returning it immediately. By seeing the `return` statement I'm assuming you have *that* block of code inside a function.

Comment: Other than the connecting to the database, that's the only other code inside the function. I'm using return as it's via AMFPHP.

Comment: I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

From [**OP's comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656638/mysql-php-search-query?noredirect=1#comment70512127_41656638),

> Other than the connecting to the database, **that's the only other code inside the function**. I'm using return as it's via AMFPHP.

Since you're using the above code block inside a function, **the problem** appears because of the `mysqli_fetch_array(...);` and the `return` statement. You're fetching only one(first) row from the result set and returning it immediately.

**The solution** is, create an empty create array and loop through the result set using `while()` loop. And in each iteration of the loop, fetch a row from the result set and push it in the array. Finally at the end of the function, simply return *that* array.

So your code should be like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%" . $searchquery . "%' ");

$resultArr = array();
while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $resultArr[] = $results;
}
return $resultArr;
```

---

**Sidenote:** If you want to see the complete result array structure, do `var_dump($resultArr);`